# group all events within period after first occurence in R

Tags: r, grouping

I have a data frame of events and am trying to group all of the events within non-overlapping 120 day periods of the first event.  So with the following example data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(
  event = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  date = as.Date(c("1992-01-03", "1992-09-07", "1992-11-26", "1993-01-29", "1993-02-18", "1993-04-02")),
  duration = c(4, 23, 60, 18, 30, 5)
)
df = df |>
  mutate(period_end = date + 120) 
df

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  event date       duration period_end
  <dbl> <date>        <dbl> <date>    
1     1 1992-01-03        4 1992-05-02
2     2 1992-09-07       23 1993-01-05
3     3 1992-11-26       60 1993-03-26
4     4 1993-01-29       18 1993-05-29
5     5 1993-02-18       30 1993-06-18
6     6 1993-04-02        5 1993-07-31
```

I need to create groups that include the events that start within 120 days from each other.
so in this case I would have groups with events A:[1] , B:[2, 3], and  C:[ 4, 5, 6].
So group B starts on 1992-9-7 and ends 1993-1-5, and event 4 is not within this window even though it starts within a 2 months of event 3, but it's past the end date of the group.  Group C would start with event 4 and extend until "1993-5-29"

I can test if each event is within the window of the previous one with `date < lag(period_end)` but this tests each event with the period before.  How can I create groups that "look" further back to close groups based on the first event in the group?

Comment: I can't think of a clever way to do this that doesn't involve a loop of some sort, since each group depends on the results of the previous group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to take the question as a practice of basic programming skills, you can try ***dynamic programming*** with loops like below

```
v <- date + 120
grp <- rep(0, length(date))
id <- 1
i <- 1
repeat {
    if (i == length(grp)) break
    for (j in i:length(date)) {
        if (date[j] <= v[i]) {
            grp[j] <- id
        } else {
            id <- id + 1
            break
        }
    }
    i <- j
}
```

and you will have the grouping information `grp`

```
> grp
[1] 1 2 2 3 3 3
```

## Data

```
date <- as.Date(c("1992-01-03", "1992-09-07", "1992-11-26", "1993-01-29", "1993-02-18", "1993-04-02"))
```

Comment: In my actual data I ran into a problem where the id for the last entry wasn't part of the previous group, so  wasn't getting assigned. Fixed by forcing assignment for the last line by adding `grp[i]<- id`  before the first `break`.